# Is there a saturating subtract between two uint8 values into int8 in Neon

Tags: arm, neon

I have to do subtraction between two unint8 vectors, and then saturating to int8 vectors. For example

```
uint8 a=8;
uint8 b=248;

subtract: a-b=-240
saturate cast: -240 -> -128 
make sure the value is in [-128, 127]
```

I want the **C API** of **arm neon** to do that

Comment: I hope your prjoect is based on an out-of-order architecture like CA9 or CA15. Otherwise, spamming the function below will MASSIVELY suffer from instruction latencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's certainly no single NEON operation to do both saturation and arithmetic from one type, to a different type, with the precision of a third intermediate type, but it does seem to be possible in two:

An unsigned widening subtraction (`vsubl`) will calculate the intermediate result without loss of precision as a uint16. Since NEON uses two's complement we take advantage of the fact that any integer underflow here is equivalent to signed subtraction, and that we still only have at most 9 bits of data, so happily cast that to a signed `int16`. We can then perform a narrowing saturation (`vqmovn`) to get that down to a signed `int8` for the desired result.

Putting that together in intrinsics gave me this, which seems to do the job:

```
int8x8_t dothething(uint8x8_t a, uint8x8_t b) {
    uint16x8_t tmp = vsubl_u8(a, b);
    return vqmovn_s16(vreinterpretq_s16_u16(tmp));
}
```